# Phoenix model with has_many relation will not update w/o preloading the relation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm working on a Phoenix application that's a personal version of Evernote. I have a `Book` model, that `has_many` `Note` records.

This is my book model:

```
defmodule Notebook.Book do
  use Notebook.Web, :model

  schema "books" do
    field :name, :string, default: ""
    has_many :notes, Notebook.Note
    belongs_to :user, Notebook.User
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
    Book changeset. Name field required.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> validate_required(:name)
  end
end
```

And I have an update endpoint in my controller:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "book" => book_params}) do
  existing_book = Repo.get(Book, id)
  changeset = Book.changeset(existing_book, book_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, book} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:ok)
      |> render("show.json", book: book)

    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render("error.json", message: changeset.errors)
  end
end
```

And a test:

```
test "with a valid jwt", %{conn: conn, jwt: jwt} do
  book = insert(:book)
  resp = conn
  |> put_req_header("authorization", "Bearer: #{jwt}")
  |> put(book_path(Endpoint, :update, book, book: %{name: "New  Book"}))
  |> json_response(:ok)

  assert resp["data"]["book"]["name"] == "New Book"
end
```

When I run my tests, I get this error:

```
** (RuntimeError) attempting to cast or change association `notes`   from `Notebook.Book` that was not loaded. Please preload your associations before manipulating them through changesets
```

The params I'm sending are only `name`. Looking into this, I found a [related issue](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1432), but since I'm not using `cast_assoc` I don't think it applies.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I understand (I think) about preloading relations in Ecto, but in this case I'm not updating the dependent `Note` records, just the one field of the `Book` record, so I should not need to preload.

The entire repo is [here](https://github.com/cdale77/notebook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using `Repo.insert` in the `update` method of `BookController`. Changing that to `Repo.update` should fix it.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'd been stuck on this for a while.